# ANDROID- why claimInterface unmounted USB?

Tags: android, android-intent, usb

First, here's the fact.

1. App is using [intent filter](https://android-er.blogspot.my/2014/02/use-intent-filter-to-detect-specified.html) which only specific USB can communicate with the app. The app **will auto-start** when the specific USB is detected.
2. One of the button app is to [browse file](https://github.com/ianhanniballake/LocalStorage) from internal and **external storage**. So, I expect the attached USB can be seen in the [list](https://github.com/ianhanniballake/LocalStorage/raw/master/art/screenshots/screenshot_picker.png?raw=true).
3. Problem with [claimInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html): During debugging, after execute `usbDeviceConnection.claimInterface(usbInterface, forceClaim);`, app will **unmounted the attached USB**, it cause the button as stated in 2 cannot list the attached USB.
4. If I delete the code, app cannot communicate with USB but USB can be seen in the list for browsing file.
5. I use this [sample](https://android-er.blogspot.my/2014/02/use-intent-filter-to-detect-specified.html) for intent filter and this [sample](https://github.com/ianhanniballake/LocalStorage) for browsing file

So, my question is, can I do claimInterface and intent filter without unmount the USB attached so that I can browse the USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for claimInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#claimInterface(android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface,%20boolean)) is pretty clear:

> Claims **exclusive access** to a `UsbInterface`

This means that no other apps nor the system provided USB `DocumentsProvider` can access that USB device any more: they're mutually exclusive.